# Android Studio перестала создавать apk

Tags: android, android-studio

Сегодня добавил рекламу AdMob в приложение, позже захожу по привычке в Build -> Generate Signed apk, пишется Gradle Build Running, и через пару секунд надпись исчезает и apk не создается. В чем проблема? Как решить ее?

Comment: удалить AdMob и проверить, генерируется ли apk (если все делаете в системах контроля версий, то это задача  на пять минут).

Comment: apk так и не генерируется, даже после удаления admob

Comment: тогда нужно попробовать запустить сборку с консоли и посмотреть как падает. Вполне возможно, что там будет стектрейс. Но для начала я бы просто рекомендовал сделать clean для всего проекта и пересборку.

Comment: я понял что вся проблема в адмобе, т.к. при другом проекте, как я только  в Gradle добавляю compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0' то просто перестает создаваться апк

Comment: вполне возможно, что Вы натолкнулись  на проблему [65k методов](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: Всё таки добавьте хоть что-то из логов. Посмотрите все вкладки внизу студии - там будут логи в т.ч. сборки и запуска проекта.